# MVC4 Routes in Area Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting confused to registering routes in an area, basically I have two URL's that I am trying to accept. One default and the other as accepting a date as a string.

Here is my Register Area code for the Area called Racing.

```
   public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        // URL Needed = Racing/Meeting/Racecards/2014-06-01
       // URL displayed = Racing/Meeting/Racecards/2014-06-01  // THIS WORKS!

        context.MapRoute(
            name: "Racecard",
            url: "Racing/{contoller}/{action}/{date}",
            defaults: new { controller="Meeting", action = "Racecards", date = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


       // URL Needed = Racing/Meeting/View/109
       // URL displayed = Racing/Meeting/View?id=109

       context.MapRoute(
           "Racing_default",
           "Racing/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

    }
```

Currently I cannot get the default to work now I have added the first route.  If I swap the order around then the first route does not pass the parameter back.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Changed the route to be:

```
        context.MapRoute(
           name: "Racecard",
           url: "Racing/{contoller}/{action}/{date}",
           defaults: new { controller="Meeting", action = "Racecards", date = UrlParameter.Optional },
           constraints: new { date = @"^\d{4}$|^\d{4}-((0?\d)|(1[012]))-(((0?|[12])\d)|3[01])$" }
       );


        context.MapRoute(
           "Racing_default",
           "Racing/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

This now matches the both urls and they work.  However when I visit a standard action Racing/Meeting/ or Racing/Meeting/HelloWorld these both now fail.

Comment: You'll need to use constraints. Currently, your default route would also match the date route. Add a constraint that defines the format of the {date} parameter.

Comment: See edit.  I cannot visit a standard URL?

Comment: You have a typo here: "Racing/{contoller}/{action}/{date}", shouldn't that be "controller" instead of "contoller"? :)

Comment: Yes but that didn't help i'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use route constraints for the first route. See this [atricle](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) for help.

Comment: OK but now I cannot visit a normal ActionResult, please see edit